# how to work on the other side of the box

Tags: css

I made a box in my website but after making the box everything I do is happening at the bottom of the box. I want to work on the other side of the box. Here is the demo code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {
                background-color: lightgrey;
                width: 200px;
                padding: 25px;
                border: 3px light grey;
                margin: 25px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src="s.png" style="width:900px;height:100px" />
        <div>
            how to work on the<br/>
            other side of box
        </div>
        <p>
            the paragraph i am wriiting i want this on the other side of my box
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: change markup as you want

Comment: What you mean by _other side_? Content flow in HTML is from left to right, from top to bottom.

Comment: Please be more specific what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need float left for your Div and Paragraph. Is that the other side of the box that you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to "float" the div/box to the left/right.

```
float:left;
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/p9y9v4kz/

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just use table

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    how to work on the other side of box
                </td>
                <td>
                    the paragraph i am writing i want this on the other side of my box
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Other side* , you mean to say left or right side?

You need to use `float:left` or `float:right`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/479dJ/3/)